# Problem with authorization in BitGo - already logged in

Tags: javascript, node.js

I started doing a small project in nodeJS and hooked it up with BitGo.
I created a test account and created a test wallet. In node I install bitgo via npm and require in code. 
Now I'm trying to use the method authenticate like this :

```
router.get('/profile', (req, res) => {
    bitgo.authenticate({
            env: 'test',
            username: 'username',
            password: 'password',
            otp: '0000000'
        })
        .then(function(user) {
            res.render('user/profile', {
                user: user
            });
        });
});
```

But it works only first time. If I refresh the page I got an error in terminal,

> Unhandled rejection Error: already logged in

Does anyone know how can I fix this error?

Comment: Have you looked at this issue on github ? https://github.com/BitGo/BitGoJS/issues/63

Comment: Yes, I looked at, but I used method authenticate. I don't use access token.

Comment: If I understood correctly, the error "already logged in" shows up when you uselessly try to authenticate while already being logged. Refreshing the page does not restarts the server, so you are still logged. This also explains why it works fine the first time.

Comment: Yes exactly. So, how can I deal with it ?

Comment: You should have a variable for holding the auth token (the one returned by the server). When the user loads the page, check the variable. If it's empty, log in, and store the token. If it's not, it means you arealready logged, so you just have to reuse the token. (I say token, but I do not know the return value of the authentication)

Comment: @Seblor , Thank you for interested :). I solved this problem using session ;) .